# Unable to paste token into command line for GitHub functions such as git pull

Tags: windows, git, github, git-for-windows

I am using the windows command line (NOT bash) for git and GitHub.  Passwords have been replaced with personal access tokens.  I have a token.  It works when I input each character manually.  It does not work when I copy and paste it into the command line.  Does anyone have a solution?  It is very time consuming to paste each and every character by hand.  Thank you for your help.

I tried copying the token from Notepad++, word, and directly from the GitHub site.  The command line will not accept it when I try to paste it.

Comment: Why do you have to *paste* every individual character? Don't you have a keyboard where you can *type* them?

Comment: @mkrieger1 A secure password these days is a long string of gobblydy gook.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of your command line window? Windows has several and they all have weird quirks about copying and pasting.

Comment: I've assumed you're using Git Bash and found a duplicate question. If that doesn't work, comment and I will reopen.

Comment: I am using the windows command prompt, not git bash.  I am not pasting individual characters, I am typing them in one by one.  I have not found a solution in the older posts.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm trying to paste a copy of my command window via snipping tool, but it will not paste.  Is there a better way to do it?  Thank you.